# Incrementing month

Tags: java, string, date

I have a string which holds a month.

```
String mon = "January";
```

Now, another string `nextMon` should hold the next month. That is, `nextMon` should be `"February"` if `mon` is `"January"`.

I get the `mon` string from a function, so it has to happen automatically.

Please tell me the easiest way to this.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Use [`java.time.Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) instead of strings.

Comment: Well, I converted it to a number with the Month class, then converted the month object to string. Then I created a random date in the form of a string with that particular month, then I convert it to calender type and increment it. Then I convert the calender type back to string, and get the month out of it. And on top of all of this, it is not working

Comment: `String nextMon = Month.valueOf(mon.toUpperCase()).plus(1).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.US);`

Answer (score 2):

As Slaw said, use `Month` for a month of the year, not a string. Parse your string into a `Month` like this:

```
    DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String monthAsString = "January";

    Month mon = monthFormatter.parse(monthAsString, Month::from);
    System.out.println(mon);
```

Output so far is:

> JANUARY

To increment. simply add 1:

```
    mon = mon.plus(1);
    System.out.println(monthFormatter.format(mon));
```

> February

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here's a little concept. It's a method where you supply a month string in either full name or a valid 3 letter abbreviation (letter case is ignored) **OR** a month number (from 1 to 12). The **next** month from the month supplied is returned.

If ***December*** is supplied then ***January*** is returned.

If ***apr*** is supplied then ***May*** is returned.

If ***6*** is supplied (June) then ***July*** is returned.

Here is the method:

```
/**
 * Returns the next month that will follow the supplied month string. Either a 
 * full month name, a three letter month name abbreviation, or a month numerical 
 * value (from 1 to 12) can be supplied to this method.<br><br>
 * 
 * @param month (Integer OR String) If String then a full month name or three 
 * letter abbreviation can be supplied. Letter case is ignored. If Integer is 
 * supplied then any value from 1 to 12 (inclusive) can be supplied.<br>
 * 
 * @return (String) The full month name that will be next after the supplied 
 * month.
 */
public static String getNextMonth(Object month) {
    String res = null;
    String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
             "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    // Is Integer supplied...
    if (month instanceof Integer && (int)month >= 1 && (int)month <= 12) {
        // Ternary used here to get desired month from Array
        res = months[(((int)month - 1) == (months.length - 1) ? 0 : (int)month)];
        return res;
    }
    // Is String supplied...
    else if ((month instanceof String && month.toString().trim().equals("") || month.toString().length() < 3 || 
            !Arrays.asList(months).toString().toLowerCase().contains(month.toString().toLowerCase()))) { 
        System.err.println("Invalid Month Supplied!" + System.lineSeparator());
        // Do what you like with this error!
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
            if (months[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(month.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                // Ternary used here to get desired month from Array
                res = months[(i == (months.length - 1) ? 0 : (i + 1))];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

To test this method you might use something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String ls = System.lineSeparator();
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter Month: ");
    String mon = input.nextLine();
    if (mon.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) { break; }  // Quit
    String nextMon;
    // Is the supplied text a integer numerical value?
    if (mon.matches("\\d+")) {
        // Convert it from string to integer.
        int monthNum = Integer.parseInt(mon);
        // Passing an integer Month value to the 
        // getNextMonth() method.
        nextMon = getNextMonth(monthNum);
    }
    else {
        // Passing a String month name or (3 letter 
        //  abreviation) to the getNextMonth() method.
        nextMon = getNextMonth(mon);
    }
    if (nextMon != null){
        System.out.println(nextMon + ls);
    }
}
```